# How to Send Email with Gmail API Using OAuth2.0 in RazorPages App on .NET 7

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, razor-pages, google-api-dotnet-client, .net-7.0

Beginner here.
I am building a new RazorPages application in .NET 7.
**I need to implement e-mail sending functionality from a Gmail account, using the new Oauth2.0 and Gmail API, without choosing the "Allow less secure apps" option.**

So far I have managed to authenticate using OAuth2.0 and list the messages in the inbox:

```
class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes =
            {
                GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,
                GmailService.Scope.GmailSend
            };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
            IList<Message> messages = request.Execute().Messages;
            Console.WriteLine("Messages:");
            if (messages != null && messages.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var labelItem in messages)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("<------- S E P A R A T O R -------->");
                    var texta = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", labelItem.Id).Execute();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", texta.Snippet);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No labels found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

However, all my attempts to send an e-mail message using Gmail API have failed. All the tutorials offer different solutions, like using MailKit, SMTP, IMAP, third-party libraries etc.

Is there an option to complete the above code so as to sent a message using plain Gmail API, without additional libraries or tools?

Any hint welcome.

Thanks!